# How to add navigation function inside async function?

Tags: react-native

I have created an async function that fetches data from api and turns red, whenever the icon is presses, however now I want just after the like function is completed it navigates to another page, however am not able to do it.
Kindly help,

Below is the way that I had tried,

```
onButtonPress = async(item) => {
    console.log(item)
    console.log(this.state.buttonColor,'hello')
  if(!this.state.likedItemIds.includes(item._id)){
    try {
      const response = await fetch("some url"+item._id);
      const resJson = await response.text();
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        likedItemIds: [...prevState.likedItemIds, item._id]
      }))

      console.log(resJson)
      if(this.state.buttonColor!=='white'){
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Wishlist')
      }
    }


    catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
 }
```

Do tell me if anything else is required and kindly help.

Comment: Did you find the answer to this?

Comment: I created a modal page, and called it vidible inside the likepress function instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState` is an asynchronous function that allows you to pass a callback as the second argument. So you can do your navigation in that callback, which will fire after `setState` is complete. This means you will navigate away from the page once the like is complete.

You can do the below:

```
onButtonPress = async(item) => {
    console.log(item)
    console.log(this.state.buttonColor,'hello')
  if(!this.state.likedItemIds.includes(item._id)){
    try {
      const response = await fetch("some url"+item._id);
      const resJson = await response.text();
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        likedItemIds: [...prevState.likedItemIds, item._id]
      }), () => { 
          // Do whatever else you need to do here (validation, etc.)
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Wishlist') 
      })
    }


    catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
 }
```